# XCode 15 does not recognize device with usb behind a corporate proxy (macOS 14)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode15, macos-sonoma

I work behind a corporate proxy connected via Cisco Anyconnect. When I am not connected to the VPN, XCode 15 does recognize my physical iPhone which is connected via cable. As soon I switch to the VPN, XCode loses the connection. It seems XCode tries to connect only via Wifi as soon I am in the corporate network. Which is weird because the finder recognizes the device via cable and without a VPN connection it works fine too.

Under "Manage run destinations" I find the following message for my iPhone:

```
Internal logic error: Connection was invalidated
Domain: com.apple.CoreDevice.ControlChannelConnectionError
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-09-28 08:17:11 +0000";
    "com.apple.dt.DVTCoreDevice.operationName" = enablePersonalizedDDI;
}
--
Transport error
Domain: com.apple.CoreDevice.ControlChannelConnectionError
Code: 0
--
The connection was interrupted.
Domain: com.apple.Mercury.error
Code: 1000
User Info: {
    XPCConnectionDescription = "<RemoteXPCPeerConnection 0x600002c8eda0> { <remote connection: 0x6000033b7200> { type = rsd, state = not-connected, remote service name = com.apple.internal.dt.coredevice.untrusted.tunnelservice, server mode = 0, protocol version number = 1, protocol feature flags = 0x6, local service version = 0, remote service version = 2, traffic class = 0, (root, reply) helo received = (1, 1), next msg id = 9, first msg id = 3, send in progress = 0, preexisting socket = -1 }";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A344)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-09-28T10:17:11+02:00
```

This issue exists since the update to macOS 14, it worked fine before. Anyone with the same issue or a solution?

Comment: I have met the same problem before, after I change my VPN to V2Ray, it is be resolved. I designed a custom rule to bypass apple and my company, which means direct to connect.